# Property InvalidDataException on instantiation

Tags: c#, instantiation, scorm-cloud-api

I'm using the Rustici Scorm Cloud API to generate a URL to preview some learning material:

- API docs: [buildCoursePreviewLaunchLink](https://cloud.scorm.com/docs/api_reference/v2/endpoints/courseservice/#buildcoursepreviewlaunchlink)
- NuGet package: [1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Com.RusticiSoftware.Cloud.V2/1.0.0)

The code creates a [LaunchLinkRequestSchema](https://cloud.scorm.com/docs/api_reference/v2/models/launchlinkrequestschema/) object with the string field `RedirectOnExitUrl` populated.  However, I get an InvalidDataException at the point of instantiation:

### Code

```
var l = new LaunchLinkRequestSchema() 
{
    RedirectOnExitUrl = "https://www.example.com"
};
```

### Exception

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException   HResult=0x80131501  
Message=RedirectOnExitUrl is a required property for  LaunchLinkRequestSchema and cannot be null  
Source=Com.RusticiSoftware.Cloud.V2   
StackTrace:
at Com.RusticiSoftware.Cloud.V2.Model.LaunchLinkRequestSchema..ctor(Nullable`1 Expiry, String RedirectOnExitUrl, Nullable`1 Tracking, String StartSco, String Culture, String CssUrl, List`1 LearnerTags, List`1 CourseTags, List`1 RegistrationTags, List`1 Additionalvalues)     
at ScormAPI_Tests.Program.Main() in
C:\...\Program.cs:line 26
```

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why I see this error, when the property is being given a value.  Can anybody please explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being thrown by the constructor

```
at Com.RusticiSoftware.Cloud.V2.Model.LaunchLinkRequestSchema..ctor
```

But you are supplying the value after construction via C#'s object initializers.

[Object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) are just syntactic sugar. The object is constructed first, and then they are set. It's exactly the same as doing:

```
var l = new LaunchLinkRequestSchema();
l.RedirectOnExitUrl = "https://www.example.com";
```

You need to supply the parameter in the constructor itself, it looks to be the second parameter from the exception.

eg

```
var l = new LaunchLinkRequestSchema(null, "https://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you.  Because VS always hints at simplifying the instantiation code by using object initializers, I thought that C# set the values as part of the instantiation.